# Pasar datos de un dbgrid a otro y cerrar formulario de consulta

Tags: delphi

Buenos dias amigos. Soy novato en esto y necesitaba una ayuda.
Tengo dos formularios en las cuales tengo un `dbgrid` en cada fromulario, el segundo formulario es de consulta de productos, y la primera es un formulario de ventas. Consegui hacer que del formulario2 pase la información al fromulario1, pero ya al pasar los datos necesito cerrar mi formulario2, pero corre un error al cerrar

```
procedure TFrmConsProd.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
dm_dados.sqlconprod.FieldByName('est_codigo').AsInteger;
dm_dados.tbl_saiproducto.Edit;
dm_dados.tbl_saiproductoSAIPROD_CODPRODUTO.AsInteger := dm_dados.sqlconprod.FieldByName('est_codigo').AsInteger;
frmconsprod.close;
end;

end.
```

Aqui una imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Necesito ayuda amigos

Comment: El aqcess violation ocurre generalmente porque estás utilizando una variable de tipo objeto que no ha sido inicializada, o que apunta a una dirección de memoria de un objeto que ya ha sido destruido. No olvides que los objetos son referencias (apuntadores, o punteros).  Dado que no identificas la línea exacta donde ocurre el error, sugiero que evalúes las variables dm_dados y frmconsprod. Alguna de estas es inválida.